# Difference between App.xaml and MainPage.xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

When I create a *cross-platform*, the common project has both `App.xaml` and `MainPage.xaml`.

On the other hand, in this [Working With Maps](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/) example, the developers eliminated `MainPage.xaml` so that the common project only has `App.xaml`.

So what's the difference between these two? And why did the tutorial above delete `MainPage.xaml` when it's the one that has the text "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" that's displayed in the emulator?

The debugger hits both.

Answer (score 4):

`App` is the main class of a Forms app that manages the lifecycle.  It is responsible, among other things, for setting the initial UI page for the app.

In the sample you're looking at it assigns the `MainPage` (the active UI page shown to the user) to an instance of `TabbedPage`.  `MainPage.xaml` is just a default page that some templates create, it doesn't have any special meaning and can be replaced as needed.

```
public App ()
{

    var tabs = new TabbedPage ();

    ...

    MainPage = tabs;
}
```